# input text field and dynamic text field doesn't display some letters in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

this is my code on frame 1

```
var inputText:String;

go.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playBtnClick);

function playBtnClick(e:MouseEvent):void {

    inputText = inputTXT.text;
    gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

And this on the 5 frame:

```
outputTXT.text = inputText;
```

between the second and fifth frame some things happen and the text display's on the fith frame but some letter are gone does someon know why this is? or what to do?

Comment: Are you using the same font? Is it embedded?

Comment: @Fygo I don't know what you mean?

Comment: I mean: Are the two textfields using different font-family / font style? If you are not using system font (_sans), you should always embed (include) the font in your flash movie

Comment: @Fygo Thanks verry much that worked!!